# Troubleshooting Facebook Authentication in Flask: Facebook authentication endpoint throws an error instead of openning an authentication dialog

Tags: facebook, flask-login

I have an implementation that is intended to allow a user to authenticate to my application via facebook. The following is the code. And just to add on that, the app is still under development so am running it from localhost:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

from flask import request, redirect
import facebook

import os

class FacebookAuth:
    def __init__(self):
        os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"
        # Facebook Oauth Config
        self.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID')
        self.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET')
        self.authorization_base_url = os.getenv('FACEBOOK_AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL')
        self.token_url = os.getenv('FACEBOOK_TOKEN_URL')
        self.redirect_uri = os.getenv('FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI')
        self.api_version = os.getenv('FACEBOOK_API_VERSION')
        
    def login(self):
        redirect_uri = facebook.GraphAPI().get_auth_url(self.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID, self.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET, self.redirect_uri)
        return redirect(redirect_uri)
    
    def callback(self):
        global access_token
        code = request.args.get('code')
        access_token = facebook.GraphAPI().get_access_token_from_code(code, self.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID, self.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET, self.redirect_uri, self.api_version)
        
        if not access_token:
            return 'Access token not obtained. Login failed.'
        
        # Retrieve user name and ID
        graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=access_token['access_token'], version=self.api_version)
        me = graph.get_object('me',)
        
        print(graph)
        id = me['id']
        name = me['name']
        
        print(id)
        print(name)
        
        redirect("/")
```

When i run the code this is what my browser returns

[Output from the facebook authentication endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQyhJ.png)

Additional info:
FACEBOOK_AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL:https://www.facebook.com/v18.0/dialog/oauth
FACEBOOK_TOKEN_URL:https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/oauth/access_token
FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI:https://localhost:5000/facebook/auth/
FACEBOOK_API_VERSION:v18.0

I tried to authenticate via facebook and after authentication the facebook authentication endpoint was suppose to redirect me to the REDIRECT_URL specified in the question

Comment: What is the actual URL of the login dialog that you are creating there?

Comment: the actual URL for the login dialog: http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Comment: I meant the actual URL that you are invoking the Facebook login dialog with. What it shows in the browser address bar, when you get that error shown in your screenshot.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id=<my_client_id>&redirect_uri=121d31370f9da9b1ee9fb60aad9c37a6&scope=h%2Ct%2Ct%2Cp%2Cs%2C%3A%2C%2F%2C%2F%2Cl%2Co%2Cc%2Ca%2Cl%2Ch%2Co%2Cs%2Ct%2C%3A%2C5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C%2F%2Cf%2Ca%2Cc%2Ce%2Cb%2Co%2Co%2Ck%2C%2F%2Ca%2Cu%2Ct%2Ch%2C%2F that is the URL leading to the error screen

Comment: So the value of your `redirect_uri` parameter is `121d31370f9da9b1ee9fb60aad9c37a6`, and your `scope` parameter has the value `h,t,t,p,s,:,/,/,l,o,c,a,l,h,o,s,t,:,5,0,0,0,/,f,a,c,e,b,o,o,k,/,a,u,t,h,/` - that makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Suggests that either your config values are wrong, or you are not passing the parameters to `facebook.GraphAPI().get_auth_url()` in the correct order.

Comment: So the problem is likely on my side not the facebook authentication endpoint, right?

Comment: It is a 100% on your end, because those values simply make no sense whatsoever, for their intended purpose. The user is supposed to get redirected to the `redirect_uri` you specify, in their browser - but `121d31370f9da9b1ee9fb60aad9c37a6` is not a URL anyone _could_ redirect me to. (Not in a way that would make any sense.)

Comment: Okay let me debug the code further, Thanks for showing interest, I appreciate it